# Convert a stringified PSCustomObject back to a PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

If I create a simple object like this

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
Toto     = 'Kevin'
Language = 'Powershell'
State    = 'Texas'
ff       =  'kaka'}
```

and I convert it to string using expression like this

```
$stringObject = "$myObject"
```

I need to convert $stringObject back to PSCustomObject so i can access property like $object.Toto $object.State...

but I can't get it working using ConvertFrom-String.

Comment: if you can't fix the glitch in choco, then you will likely need to parse the string and build a new object. you can split the string and act on each part by adding each to a new hashtable & converting that to a PSCustomObject when you have the whole property list converted. it's ugly, tho. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Yes yes, possible but I searching for a more clean way to do it

Comment: Naive approach `[PSCustomObject]( Invoke-Expression ($stringObject -replace "\=", "='" -replace "\;", "';" -replace "\}", "'}"))`

Comment: Thank you JosefZ, this is working, i wonder why   there is no simple method for doing this conversion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[PSCustomObject]( Invoke-Expression ($stringObject -replace "\=", "='" -replace "\;", "';" -replace "\}", "'}"))
```

is working for me